# How can I change the x axis values to names of months of the year in multiple chart using R

Tags: r

[image: Output of multiple line chart]

I want someone to explain how to change the x axis values to months of the year i.e. **Jan2020**, **Feb2020**, ..., **Dec2020**.  Here are my code that generated the chart:

```
library(ggplot2)
library(reshape2)
dt$Time <- seq(nrow(dt))

dt.df <- melt(dt, measure.vars = c("Na", "Mg", "K", "Ca","Mn","Fe","Cu","Zn","Cd","Pb"))

ggplot(dt.df, aes(x = Time, y = value)) +
  geom_line(aes(color = variable)) +
  facet_grid(variable ~ ., scales = "free_y") +
  labs(x = "Month/Year", y = "Values")+
  theme(legend.position="none")
```

Comment: Where's `dt` come from? Can you pls include sample data in that format to make the question reproducible?

Answer (score 0):

Does this help?

```
ggplot(mtcars, aes(x = mpg/3, y = wt)) +
  geom_line(aes(color = cyl)) +
  labs(x = "Month/Year", y = "Values")+
  scale_x_continuous(breaks = 1:12, labels = paste0(month.abb[1:12],"2020"), limits = c(1,12)) +
  theme(legend.position="none")
```

[image]

Comment: The code works perfectly. The next chart has 24 months, starting from **Nov2017** and end at **Oct2019**, how do I change the ```breaks``` and ```limits```?

Comment: Is this possible in **ggplot**?

Comment: You could either create a vector with the labels you want and feed that into `labels = ` like above, or I think easier to convert the underlying Time values to a date format first.

Comment: How? I don't understand. Will the **label** contain the starting month and the last month?

Comment: Can you please make your question reproducible with the question you want answered? It's less helpful for other users to put new / modified questions in the comments.

Comment: I will take the question all over

Comment: I have reframed my qustion here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67842983/how-to-make-months-of-the-year-my-x-axis-using-xyplot. Kindly check and respond.